# Receive windows manager notifications of display changes

Tags: window, linux, x-window

Is there a way for emacs to receive display changes notification from the windows manager? I understand this might be an OS dependent question, so I'm particularly interested in the interaction between emacs and Gnome 3 windows manager (on Linux of course).

I'd like emacs to invoke certain functions when such event occurs.

Comment: Can you go into more detail about which events you're interested in, and what how you want Emacs to respond?

Comment: FYI this article is longish, but excellent reading, and I suspect it is somewhat related to your question: https://www.facebook.com/notes/daniel-colascione/buttery-smooth-emacs/10155313440066102/ (the notes on SIGIO in particular).

Comment: So in particular I would like to have an emacs hook when a window changes display.

Comment: And none of `C-h i g (elisp)Window Hooks` is sufficient?  (n.b. Lots of changes in that area in 27.1).  I can't tell what "changes display" means, btw.

Comment: FWIW if you can tell gnome3 to send SIGUSR1 or SIGUSR2 to Emacs whenever it does the thing you're interested in, you can write custom handlers for those two signals in elisp.

Comment: Thank y'all. @phils, I could not find anything there, but is seems `'focus-in-hook` might do the trick: when I click emacs' window border to move it to a different monitor it will call this hook, and the same will happen if I press the shortcuts to move a window.